# Can I run Ubuntu using wayland?

Tags: 12.10, xserver, wayland

So, I compiled wayland from official git, saw that it successfully run wenston, now, can I make it run my desktop somehow ?

Comment: You should read this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland

Comment: `wenston` or `whetstone`? which one is it?

Comment: @saji89 package is wenston

Comment: @LnxSlck , I read the wiki but it doesn't answer the question, can I ,now , use wenston for my desktop or not ?

Comment: Short answer:No. Long Answer:Probably, no. Everything still runs on X11, so wait until they been "fixed" to work with it.